# $this->redirect showing data in url

Tags: url, redirect, yii

I am using $this->redirect to redirect from one action to another

> $this->redirect(array('site/payment','bookingID'=>$bookingID,'orderID'=>$model->quoteNo,'amount'=>$rent));

But I don't why it showing parameter in url

> https://www.siteurl.com/bookingID/5/orderID/123456/amount/220.00

How do I hide my data from user?

Comment: it showing parameters because you are passing them. Remove parameters from your redirect if you don't want to show them to user. `$this->redirect(['site/payment']);`

Comment: What you expect your url to be in this case?

Comment: I am redirecting from one action to another and i want those parameter to be pass for next action for future calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using sessions. You can access current Session with `Yii::$app->session`. You can send those parameters in session.. For Example

```
public function actionOne() {
    // Check if the Session is Open, and Open it if it isn't Open already
    if (!Yii::$app->session->getIsActive()) {
        Yii::$app->session->open();
    }
    Yii::$app->session['bookingID'] = $bookingID;
    Yii::$app->session['orderID'] = $model->quoteNo;
    Yii::$app->session['amount'] = $rent;
    Yii::$app->session->close();
    $this->redirect(['site/payment']);
}

public function actionTwo() {
    // Then you can get those values like this...
    $bookingID= Yii::$app->session['bookingID'];
    $orderID= Yii::$app->session['orderID'];
    $amount= Yii::$app->session['amount'];
   // do whatever you want..
}
```